# Cannot download a file using HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, file-io, ms-word, nullpointerexception

I want to download a MS Word 2003 document that I am creating with the content `myString` in it.
I have used the following code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(templatePathFilename));
HttpServletResponse response = new MyHttpServletResponse();
response.setContentType ("application/msword"); 
response.setHeader ("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+outgoingFileName); 
ServletOutputStream myOut = response.getOutputStream();
myOut.write(myString.getBytes());
myOut.flush();
myOut.close();
```

But the line `myOut.write(myString.getBytes())` gives a NullPointerException.
`MyHttpServletResponse` is a class that eclipse has produced by default when I quick fix the error generated. Do I need to modify that class?
Can anyone please help!

EDIT: The actual code i am working on is as below:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(templatePathFilename));
String outgoingFileName = outputPathFilename;
response.setContentType("application/msword"); 
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+outgoingFileName);
OutputStream myOut = response.getOutputStream();
try {
String thisLine;
while ((thisLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if(thisLine.contains("##"))
    {
    for (java.util.Enumeration e = FrontSheetMap.keys(); e.hasMoreElements();{
     String name = (String) e.nextElement();
     String value = FrontSheetMap.get(name).toString();
     thisLine= thisLine.replaceAll("##" + name.toUpperCase() + "##", value);
    }
   }
   myOut.write(thisLine);
   myOut.write("\n");
  }
  myOut.flush();
}catch(Exception e){}
```

The while loop replaces the placeholders in the input file with required values and the new content in `thisLine` is to be written on the output file. I need a download option which pops up on clicking the link which executes this code.

Comment: Where is myString being declared and defined? Also, are you sure it's not that value that is null?

Comment: yes, its not null. The function does not work even if I write `myOut.write(1234);` or `myOut.write("hello".getBytes());` or any other string directly into it.

Comment: Does your reader need to get passed into something? I see you declared it on the first line, but I don't see where you actually used it. I haven't done File IO in ages, but I'm assuming you included that for a reason.

Comment: @SunmitGirme Is MyHttpServletResponse is your response wrapper?

Comment: @jmort253: yeah, the reader function is to read a different file and write that content into the writer. But the writer itself is not working, so what is in `reader` does not matter as of now. And the reader and writer fucntionality works well if I download the file directly on to the file system by specifying the path.

Comment: Where is this code written ? I mean inside a servlet or JSP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned `MyHttpServletResponse` *is a class that eclipse has produced by default when I quick fix the error generated*, that seems to be the problem.

Your code **should be inside some servlet/JSP** and the HttpServletResponse object should be taken from the container (which is passed to service/doGet/doPost methods).

What **you are using is a default/dummy implementation** of `HttpServletResponse` which gives `response.getOutputStream();` as null. If you use the container provided objects, your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks, the NullPointerException does not occuranymore. But the function still does not pop-up a decision box to download the word document. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @SunmitGirme Same problem. Any solution?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a Java EE platform to perform the download operation to occur then the safest way is to do it through a servlet. A Sample Download servlet should Look like below,

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.*; 
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class DownloadFile extends HttpServlet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        // Prepare the File Read.
        String fileName = request.getParameter("fileName");
        fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, fileName.length());
        String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, fileName.length());
        String filePath = "C:/temp/" + fileName;
        FileInputStream fileToDownload = new FileInputStream(filePath);

        // Prepare the Headers.
        if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("txt")) {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
        } else if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("doc")) {
            response.setContentType("application/msword");
        } else if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf")) {
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        } else if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg")) {
            response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        } else if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("jpeg")) {
            response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        }
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        response.setContentLength(fileToDownload.available());

        // Download the file.
        int c;
        while ((c = fileToDownload.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(c);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        fileToDownload.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not download. The code executes, but it is supposed to give a pop-up to save the file, but it doesn't.

Comment: In the above code u can see i am reading the file from the server location on "C:\Temp" ok so u have to change the  " filePath " as per your requirement, any yes this servlet will generate a save dialog box to save the file in your desired location.

Answer (score 0):

Add your filename to the header like below (Filename should include the extention like if you have a word document named abc the file name should be abc.doc "i.e. with extention"), no need to check the extension and then set the content type

httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="
                      + fileName);

The remaining code remains the same and try it now , you should be able to see a popup asking your permission to open a this word document.

Below is a code snipet which is working for me

```
        OutputStream outputStream=httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
        httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="
                  + fileName);



        //**Take the data from input stream and write it on outputstream
        try{
            IOUtils.copy(documentumClientSession.getFile(fileName,dbpNum), outputStream);
        }catch(Exception exp){
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am using apache commons api that's why you can see org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils the class being used but you can replace it with your own loop in the code.